# Unexpected behaviour in bash function

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm scratching my head why a bash script won't work.  I've condensed it to the following:

```
#! /bin/bash

function syncuser()
{
        cat ~nagios/.ssh/authorized_keys
        cat /home/$1/.ssh/authorized_keys
        cat ~$1/.ssh/authorized_keys
}
    
syncuser nagios
```

When run, I would have thought that each of the above entries would have outputted the nagios users authorised keys - however while the top 2 entries work, the bottom one fails with

cat: '~nagios/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory

It appears my understanding of something related to "~user" representing that users home directory is off.   **Can anyone advise why the last entry is not producing the expected output?**

Comment: [From the manual, emphasis added:](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) "The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution **(done in a left-to-right fashion)**; word splitting; and filename expansion." Tilde and parameter (which `$1` is) are done in the same pass, left-to-right.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for that.   Do you know of any way I can make that last command perform correctly without grepping the passwd file?  (ie I can't assume that the users home directory will be in /home)

Comment: Actually, I think I just found the answer - https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-get-a-users-home-directory-from-the-username-in-a-variables-in-bash/ - userhome=$(eval echo ~$user)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it.